# Angular JS Authentication maintaince

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I'm looking for the best architectural solution.

I have following html:

```
<body ng-controller="individualFootprintController as $ctrl">
<div ng-hide="$ctrl.authenticated">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            With Corporate Account: <a href="/login/corporate">click here</a>
</div>
```

And controller:

```
function individualFootprintController($http) {
        var self = this;
        $http.get("/is_auth").success(function () {
            self.authenticated = true;
        })
            .error(function() {
                self.authenticated = false;
            }
        );
}
```

**Questions:**

1) Is this controller appropriate place for having this logic?

2) I want to have actual "is_authenticated" value. How can make this happen, if I want to fire request only once

Answer (score 0):

Presumably authentication with the backend requires an actual token of some kind. I.e. you don't just set a `true`/`false` flag somewhere and call it authentication, but to be able to communicate with the backend you need to include a username/password/cookie/token in the request or the request will be denied.

A controller is a bad place to store such a thing, since controllers aren't permanent. Or at least you shouldn't make them permanent to the extent possible. Also, storing the token in a controller doesn't allow anything else access to it.

1. Whether you are logged in or not should be based on whether you have a valid authentication token or not.
2. This token must be stored in a canonical place, best suited for that is a service.
3. Other services get the token from there and also decide whether the app is currently "logged in" based on whether a token is available.

A rough sketch of how that should be structured:

```
app.service('AuthService', function () {
    this.token = null;
});

app.service('FooService', function (AuthService, $http) {
    $http.get(..., AuthService.token, ...)
});

app.controller('LoginStatusController', function (AuthService) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'isLoggedIn', {
        get: function () { return AuthService.token != null; }
    });
});
```

```
<div ng-controller="LoginStatusController as ctrl">
    <div ng-hide="ctrl.isLoggedIn">
```

When you actually log in and obtain a token, you set `AuthService.token` and it will be available to all other services and controllers. If and when the token becomes invalid or unset, all services and controllers lose their authenticated status.

Comment: He's using cookies authentication.

Comment: And in a jwt auth scenari, the fact that "I have a token" doesn't mean you are authenticated. Being authenticated is much more like "my token is valid", which must be checked often.

Comment: If the token is implicit, well, then replace it with just a `true`/`false` flag. And yes, you won't know whether your token is valid or not until you try it. So when it fails, invalidate it.

Comment: How do you know OP is using cookies?

Comment: 1) because `$http.get("/is_auth")` doesn't explicitly send a token, so I infer it implicitly sends a cookie. Unless he has an interceptor than he didn't told us about.
2) because "is authenticated" logic make us think some sort of "is there a session" on the backend. With a token you need to deserialize token and check user existence. When you have done this, you naturally return the user. I mean with cookie you can have a session without a user; with token this would be strange.

Comment: Though I also add your logic to "invalidate token on API backend error" but this is a much harder thing than it looks like. Error handling must be graceful to allow other errors, like "I received a 400, this is not authentication trouble", but furthermore "I received a 403 because I can't do this, BUT that doesn't mean I'm not authenticated". The backend needs to send understandable codes which have to be understood by client.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is the following :

Using *[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)*

- Take advantage of the `resolve` hook (which resolves some args and inject them into controller), and define my routes as subroutes of a main one which checks auth on each route change

  **scripts/services/user.js**

  ```
   angular.module('yourmodule')
    .service('userSrv', function ($http, $q) {
      var srv = {};

      srv.getAuthenticatedUser = function() {
        return $http.get("/authenticated_user");
      };

      return srv;
    });
  ```

  **scripts/routes.js**

  ```
  angular
   .module('yourmodule')
   .config(function ($stateProvider) {
     $stateProvider
      .state('authenticated', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view />',
        controller: 'AuthenticatedCtrl',
        resolve: {
          signedInUser: function(userSrv, $q) {
            return userSrv.getAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(function(null, function() {
              //Catch any auth error, likely 403
              //And transform it to null "signedInUser"
              //This is the place to handle error (log, display flash)
              return $q.resolve(null);
            });
          }
        }
      })
      .state('authenticated.myspace', {
        url: '/myspace',
        templateUrl: 'views/myspace.html'
      });
   });
  ```
- Take advantage of $scope inheritance inside your view

  **scripts/controllers/authenticated.js**

  ```
   angular.module('yourmodule')
    .controller('AuthenticatedCtrl', function (signedInUser, $scope, $state) {
     //Here you set current user to the scope
     $scope.signedInUser= signedInUser;

     $scope.logout = function() {
       //this is where you would put your logout code.
       //$state.go('login');
     };
   });
  ```

  **views/myspace.html**

  ```
   <!-- here you call parent state controller $scope property -->
   <div ng-hide="signedInUser">
     <h1>Login</h1>
       With Corporate Account: <a href="/login/corporate">click here</a>
   </div>
  ```

1) I want to have actual "is_authenticated" value. How can make this happen, if I want to fire request only once
My solution asks for authenticated user on each route change. This seems strange but this is actualy viable and fast. The query should not be > 30ms it's a very small SELECT under the hood. THOUGH, asking "am I authenticated" and "get the authenticated user" are pretty the same thing, except one return a boolean, and the other return the user. I suggest, like I just show you, to handle "am I authenticated" question by requesting the authenticated user, then booleaning it with "if(user)" (null value handling).

2) Is this controller appropriate place for having this logic?
Yes and no. As you can see, the controller is the very place to "set the user to the scope thing", but scope inheritance allow you to not repeat it for each route. Though, http api logic should be ported to a service, and routing event ("get the authenticated user for this page, please" is a routing event IMHO) should be set in a separate file.

NB: if you need complete route "protection" (like redirection on non-authenticated, ask another question and I'll be glad to answer it)